# How to save path to image in the database (using a normal TEXT field)

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, listview

I want to make a listview with thumb images in each row and when I stock those images in the database, the querying process became very slow and uneffective, so I am now considering to save a path to the images in assets folder or res folder instead,can anyone tell me how to do that, thanks

An example or tutorial would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try use getAssets() method from Context. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets()

Hope, it help you!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just save the file name?

Then assuming you know the path just load the filename from the database and add it to the path when loading the image. I am doing this to load images from the net.

If you are trying to load a resource you could save the int value that is used to identify the resource.

Comment: It's a good idea, I'm gonna try and come back to tell you what's the result,thx